# After WordPress updated to 4.8.1, RSS feed stopped enclosing audio files?

Tags: wordpress, rss, podcast

We are using the automatic RSS feeds created by WordPress to convert a page into a podcast. After WordPress updated to `4.8.1`, RSS stopped enclosing the audio files and I can't figure out why.

Page in question: `www.faithandvictory.com/sermons/`

Feed: `www.faithandvictory.com/sermons/feed/`

Anybody know why it would stop and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party RSS plugin or something? The XML looks malformed and incomplete. My guess is the php function used to create the feed is no longer working as it should.

Comment: No, we're just using the automatic feeds that wordpress creates on it's own and then running it through feedburner. FeedBurner is still working, just not picking up the audio files because wordpress stopped enclosing them. I thought that too, but they didn't update any of the feed.php files so i'm not sure where the code broke. :/

Comment: How are you embedding it on the post? Is it with shortcodes? They did change some things about that in 4.8, introduced some audio/video widgets. Might be something to do with that.

Comment: It does appear to be using shortcodes. We're just using our theme's upload box to add the file there but when I look at the source html, it is definitely using an audio shortcode.

Comment: I would suggest contacting the theme developer then. They probably need to push some kind of update as a result of the main WordPress update. Seems like that might be the issue here.